# XSLT doesn't show as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't know for sure what is wrong, or what is missing in my XSLT file, the result doesn't show up as expected, in which every code outside the `<html></html>` doesn't show up!

I also try to switch from `xsl:output method="html"` to `xsl:output method="xml"`, it doesn't work, either.  The result shows only BOOKS STORE and nothing else below.

Please give me a hand. Thank you!

Here is the XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="books1.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#fff">
    <h1>BOOKS STORE </h1>

    </body>

    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ITEM">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BOOKS>
      <ITEM CAT="MMP">
         <TITLE>Pride and Prejudice</TITLE>
         <AUTHOR>Jane Austen</AUTHOR>
         <PUBLISHER>Modern Library</PUBLISHER>
         <PUB-DATE>2002-12-31</PUB-DATE>
         <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE>
         <PRICE>9</PRICE>

      </ITEM>
      <ITEM CAT="P">
         <TITLE>Wuthering Heights</TITLE>
         <AUTHOR>Charlotte Brontë</AUTHOR>
         <PUBLISHER>Penguin Classics</PUBLISHER>
         <PUB-DATE>2002-12-31</PUB-DATE>
         <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE>
         <PRICE>9.040000000000001</PRICE>

      </ITEM>
      <ITEM CAT="P">
         <TITLE>Tess of the d'Urbervilles</TITLE>
         <AUTHOR>Thomas Hardy</AUTHOR>
         <PUBLISHER>Bantam Classics</PUBLISHER>
         <PUB-DATE>1984-05-01</PUB-DATE>
         <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE>
         <PRICE>12.5</PRICE>

      </ITEM>
      <ITEM CAT="P">
         <TITLE>Jude the Obscure</TITLE>
         <AUTHOR>Thomas Hardy</AUTHOR>
         <PUBLISHER>Penguin Classics</PUBLISHER>
         <PUB-DATE>1998-09-01</PUB-DATE>
         <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE>
         <PRICE>7</PRICE>

      </ITEM>
      <ITEM CAT="H">
         <TITLE>The Big Over Easy</TITLE>
         <AUTHOR>Jasper Fforde</AUTHOR>
         <PUBLISHER>Hodder &amp; Stoughton</PUBLISHER>
         <PUB-DATE>2005-07-11</PUB-DATE>
         <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE>
         <PRICE>14.55</PRICE>

      </ITEM>
      <ITEM CAT="P">
         <TITLE>The Eyre Affair</TITLE>
         <AUTHOR>Jasper Fforde</AUTHOR>
         <PUBLISHER>Penguin</PUBLISHER>
         <PUB-DATE>2003-02-25</PUB-DATE>
         <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE>
         <PRICE>15</PRICE>

      </ITEM>
   </BOOKS>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting any additional output is that you don't have an `xsl:apply-templates` in this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#fff">
    <h1>BOOKS STORE </h1>

    </body>

    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Add one like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body bgcolor="#fff">
        <h1>BOOKS STORE </h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

You also have an extra `</xsl:template>`.

One other thing is that you have ambiguous template matches for `ITEM`. You'll have to use just one.

Your stylesheet should look something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body bgcolor="#fff">
                <h1>BOOKS STORE </h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>         
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/></h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that since you are matching `ITEM` and then doing an `xsl:apply-templates`, you will get duplicate titles output. You will also get the text from all of the other elements in `ITEM` because of XSLTs [built-in rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

This should at least get you started. Ask more questions if any come up.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel! I copy your code and paste in, but the `TITLE` parts don't show up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Get rid of the first template matching ITEM. You almost certainly don't want two templates matching the same thing.

In the second one, remember that XML is case-sensitive. You want to process TITILE not title.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but no TITLE shows up below the BOOKS STORE text.  Any idea why???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you could show a required output XML, that will greatly help.

I'm taking a very wild guess here. Do you want to list all "TITLE"s below "BOOKS STORE"?

In that case, you can try

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body bgcolor="#fff">
            <h1>BOOKS STORE </h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="//ITEM/TITLE">
                <TITLE><xsl:value-of select="."/></TITLE>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>         
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Joel, Yes it works and it works, too if I place your `<xsl:for-each...</xsl:for-each>` below `</html>`.  But if I create a new `xsl:template-match` (as Daniel's suggestion) and put your code in, it doesn't show up anything below BOOKS STORE! What should I have in `<xsl:template match="???">` ? If I try `<xsl:template match="BOOKS">`, it doesn't show anything, but BOOKS STORE.  I try `<xsl:template match="ITEM">`, it shows nothing, but BOOKS STORE!!!  Then, if I try `<xsl:template match="/">`, the BOOKS STORE disappears, it shows result of your code, only!   Please give me a hand.  Thanks

Comment: You have shown your input XML above. Please post your required output XML.